# How to use g_timeout_add()?

Tags: c, timeout, gtk3

I'm having a problem using `g_timeout_add`. The function I'm calling is:

```
gboolean time_handler(GtkWidget *widget, GtkWidget *sum) {
    if (widget == NULL) return FALSE;
    gchar *display;
    display = g_strdup_printf("%d", globalCounter);         //convert num to str
    gtk_label_set_text (GTK_LABEL(sum), display); //set label to "display"
    g_free(display); 

    return TRUE;
}
```

main...

```
g_timeout_add(1000, (GSourceFunc) time_handler, (window, sum))
```

This is the warning I get:

```
gtkp2.c:66:60: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
g_timeout_add(1000, (GSourceFunc) time_handler, (window,sum));
```

While running the program I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: I don't know anything about `g_timeout_add()` specifically, but it looks like (according to the warning) that calling `g_timeout_add(1000, (GSourceFunc) time_handler, (window, sum))` is the same as `g_timeout_add(1000, (GSourceFunc) time_handler, sum)`. Is there supposed to be a function call that is missing?

Comment: What is `(window,sum)` intented to mean?

Comment: Asking questions and then refuse to give any feedback is not exactly the behaviour expected at SO. -1.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at the manual for [g_timeout_add](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add) and [GSourceFunc](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#GSourceFunc).

There we see:

```
gboolean
(*GSourceFunc) (gpointer user_data);
```

and

```
guint
g_timeout_add (guint interval,
               GSourceFunc function,
               gpointer data);
```

This means you have 2 basic errors in your code:

```
gboolean time_handler(GtkWidget *widget, GtkWidget *sum)
```

1. Your function does not follow the definition of `GSourceFunc` as it is only allowed to take 1 single parameter.
   The compiler probably told you about this error becouse you have a cast to the proper type in your code. If you use the correct type, no cast should be required.

If GTK does not pass 2 parameters to your function (how should it know about your invalid function signature?) but you access that parameter and try to dereference it as a pointer, you invoke undefined behaviour which manifests as a segmentation fault in this case.

2. You try to pass **2** pointers via **1** parameter. 
   As the compiler told you, the left operand does not have any effect at all.

If you want to pass 2 values, you need to define a struct and pass a pointer to such a struct:

```
typedef struct{
  GtkWidget *widget,
  GtkWidget *sum
} myParameters; 


gboolean time_handler(gpointer *par) {
  myParams *params = par;
  ...
}
...

myParams param = {widget, sum};
g_timeout_add(1000, time_handler, &params);
// Make sure that lifetime of params does not end before your handler might be called! Local variables in main are OK for this.
```